# Linux bash command -backup=numbered. Put the number BEFORE the file extension

Tags: linux, bash, find, git-bash, cp

Using a one-line bash command with GitBash on windows, using `find` and `cp`, I am backing up a bunch of script files that exist in multiple sub-directories.  I am currently backing them up to a single directory.  As you can imagine, naming conflicts arise.  This is easy enough to avoid with the `--backup=numbered` option which creates a copy of the file.  However, the problem with this is that it puts the number AFTER the file extension, naming the file like this: `example.js.~2~`.  What I want is to preserve the file extension and name the file like this: `example2.js` rather than putting the number after the file extension.  Is there any way to do this?

Another option would be to prepend the directory name (from the directory that it is being copied from) to the file that is being copied instead of adding a number.  I would accept either of these as a solution.

Here is what I have so far:

```
find . -path "*node_modules*" -prune -o -type f \( -name '*.js' -or -name '*.js.map' -or -name '*.ts' -or -name '*.json' \) -printf "%h\n" -exec cp {} --backup=numbered "/c/test/" \;
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Why `\0\n`, that defeats the whole purpose of using `\0`

Comment: Good catch.  Thank you.  I will remove it from my post in case anybody comes here and wants to use what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

what about :

```
#!/bin/bash

# your find command here
FILES=$(find . -type f .....)

# loop through files and create a new filename with the path within ( slashes replaced by underscores
for FILE in $FILES; do
    NEW_FILENAME=$(printf "%s" "$FILE" | sed s/\\//_/g)
    cp "$FILE" "/c/test/${NEW_FILENAME}"
done
```

from your question, I am unsure if a one liner is mandatory...